# How to implement One Time registration with REST APIs in android

Tags: android, node.js, rest, authentication, oauth-2.0

I am developing an app which will be having onetime registration like whatsapp. Please tell me how to authenticate a user and the subsequent API calls. Can i implement the same with OAuth 2.0? How can I secure the API calls.?

Comment: Hi you can use database for store Id and and whenever you need to logout then that value to -1.If you don't want logout then keep it that value in db.

Comment: Hi Saveen: Thanks for the reply. But how can i authenticate a user?

Comment: You can use API for authentication,like you need enter phone no and name etc then server end return you one id for that user.. You can authenticate like this